# Using datareaders with sqltransactions

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, datareader

I am using `SqlTransaction`s in my code for roll back purpose. Within the transaction I got multiple statements to be executed with may include selects inserts and updates. All these statements are within the scope of the `sqltransaction`. Everything works fine just for one problem. I am using `datareader`s for select statements . And these readers are closed once they are used. This forces the connection to be lost and every thing fails. Does any one have a solution on whether I can use `datareader`s within a `sqltransaction`??

Answer (score 4):

A DataReader will only close the connection if the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` option was set when calling `ExecuteReader`.

You should be OK if you avoid setting this option.

Answer (score 2):

You should open the SqlConnection by itself.
The SqlDataReader doesn't close the SqlConnection when you close the DataReader

For example:

```
using(SqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction("myTransaction");
    .....

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, cn);

    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        .....
    }

    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sqlString1, cn);
    using(SqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        .....
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Hello i keep getting these error saying that There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. what could be the solution to this

Comment: Try to encapsulate every datareader inside a `using` statement. This will guarantees the call to Close and Dispose of the datareader.

Comment: This is fine... I got a lot of datareaders used >100... Is there any way wherer i can close the datareazader on the connection is open before executing the next reader?

Comment: Yes, call Close on everyone, but then, just implement the `using` and you are on the `right practice` path.